# fetching all phone numbers from address book

Tags: iphone, sdk

I want fetch all phone numbers from address book and i want to store in one array.
For that am writing this code,but am getting  this error at second line Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

```
ABRecordRef person;
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumberProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSArray* phoneNumbers = (NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneNumberProperty);
```

//    CFRelease(phoneNUmberProperty);

```
NSLog(@"Phone numbers = %@", phoneNumbers);
[phoneNumbers release];
```

please help me what are changes can i do.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`ABRecordCopyValue` will not get you all the phone numbers of a address book. You can use this to look up a property of 1 person. Use `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` to get all the persons from the address book first.